# How to run "npm start" run forever

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, webpack

[when the status is online i am running the port on 8014 its still not running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmHVi.png)

[when i use pm2 start tools/srcServer.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mh9yG.png)

```
"scripts": {
"prestart": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
"start": "npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src",
"open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
"test": "mocha --reporter progress tools/testSetup.js \"src/**/*.test.js\"",
"test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch",
"clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
"remove-dist": "node_modules/.bin/rimraf ./dist",
"build:html": "babel-node tools/buildHtml.js",
"prebuild": "npm-run-all clean-dist test build:html",
"build": "babel-node tools/build.js",
"postbuild": "babel-node tools/distServer.js"
}
```

I am running the node with npm start I need to run the node to run run the server forever.

I tried using the command "forever start -c "npm start" ./" its not showing

Comment: Check pm2 for running your scripts forever

Comment: @ShubhamJain i have attached an image can you check and let me know the command i am using pm2 start tools/server.js status showing online but port not running and when i check pm2 list showing status errored

Comment: Do you have any github repo for your project. I cannot debug the problem from here.

Comment: Also add result of command `pm2 logs 0`

Comment: having bitbucket repo

Comment: @ShubhamJain send your mailid i will send

Comment: jain.shub28@gmail.com

Comment: @ShubhamJain i have mailed you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run `npm start` from `pm2` you can run `pm2 start npm -- start`. This will run any command that is written within package.json start section.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to use PM2 (Node process manager: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/)?

Comment: I have installed pm2 using npm install pm2 -g.
What was the command used for running server forever.

Comment: pm2 start `name of file`

Comment: If you see in the scripts that i asked in the question i am running multiple, what was the command

Comment: previously i suppose to run npm start with all files run parallely. like tools/srcServer.js and tools/testSetup.js

Comment: @ShubhamJain I have attached an image what the issue i am facing when i use pm2 start tools/srcServer.js

Comment: we don't run pm2 because the license will not allow me in this particular context...